# ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.WriteListener after upgrading spring security past 4.1.5

Tags: spring-security

when upgrading spring security past 4.1.5 we experience a ClassNotFoundException looking for javax.servlet.WriteListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading spring security core and associate packages past 4.1.5 brings in a dependency on version 3.1.0 of the "provided" scope servlet api which contains a new class "WriteListener". The previous version of javax.servlet-api, 3.0.1, does not contain this class. This dependency is scoped as "provided" because it is part of the tomcat deployment.